# What does the composition "length of sum" mean?

Tags: haskell, types, composition

I was playing with types in Haskell and accidentally discovered `length . sum` is valid. Is there some semantic meaning that should allow this to work, or is this merely a wart of the type definitions? I've written each of the type definitions below.

```
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
length . sum :: (Foldable t1, Foldable t2, Num (t1 a)) => t2 (t1 a) -> Int
```

The only scenario where I can make sense of it would be summing chars into a string, and then you'd be able to get the length of that string. However, sum is only able to take in a foldable type of numbers, so that couldn't work.

Comment: The type constraint `Num (t1 a)` should give you a hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a trivial example.

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

xs :: [Identity Int]
xs = map Identity [0..9]

result :: Int
result = length . sum $ xs

main :: IO ()
main = print result -- 1
```

Let's understand what's happening.

1. First, we sum all elements of `xs`. Therefore, `sum xs` is `Identity 0 + ... + Identity 9` which evaluates to `Identity 45`. Note that `Num a => Identity a` is an instance of `Num`.
2. Next, we find the length of `sum xs`. Therefore, `length . sum $ xs` is `length $ Identity 45` which evaluates to `1` because there is exactly one element in any `Identity` data structure.

This makes sense if you look at the signature of `length . sum`.

```hs
length . sum :: (Foldable g, Foldable f, Num (f a)) => g (f a) -> Int
```

First, we traverse `g` and find the `sum` of all the `f a` within `g`. The definition of `sum` depends upon the type `f a`. The result is an `f a`. Then, we find the `length` of the resulting `f a`.